# Python parsing tac_plus configuration file

Tags: python, parsing, configuration

I'm trying to find the best way to parse the configuration file for tac_plus.It would be good to be able to transform it to JSON format so that I can store it in a NoSQL DB.

Here's a sample of the configuration:

```
id = spawnd {
    listen = {
        port = 49
    }
    spawn = {
        instances min = 1
        instances max = 10
    }
    background = yes
}

id = tac_plus {
    access log = /var/log/tacacs/%Y/%m/%d/access.log
    accounting log = /var/log/tacacs/%Y/%m/%d/acct.log

    mavis module = external {    
        setenv LDAP_SERVER_TYPE = "microsoft"
        setenv LDAP_HOSTS = "ads01:3268 ads02:3268"
        setenv LDAP_SCOPE = sub
        setenv LDAP_BASE = "dc=example,dc=com"
        setenv LDAP_FILTER = "(&(objectclass=user)(sAMAccountName=%s))";
        setenv LDAP_USER = tacacs@example.com
        setenv LDAP_PASSWD = Secret123
        setenv AD_GROUP_PREFIX = tacacs
        setenv USE_TLS = 0
        exec = /usr/local/lib/mavis/mavis_tacplus_ldap.pl
    }

    login backend = mavis
    pap backend = mavis

    host = world {
        address = ::/0
        welcome banner = "Welcome\n"
        key = cisco
    }

    host = helpdesklab {
        address = 192.168.34.16/28
    }
    group = admin {
        default service = permit
        service = shell {
            default command = permit
            default attribute = permit
            set priv-lvl = 15
        }
    }  
    group = helpdesk {
        default service = permit
        service = shell {
            default command = permit
            default attribute = permit
            set priv-lvl = 1
        }
        enable = deny "enter code here"
        member = admin@helpdesklab
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you expect the output to look? say for the mavis module?

Answer (score 0):

You could store it as a JSON in a file and just load it from there.

Make a file called conf.json:

```
{ 
  spawnd : { ... },
  tac_plus: { ... }
}
```

Then use python load it:

```
import json

with open('conf.json') as rdr:
    config = json.loads(rdr.read())

config['tac_plus']
```

Comment: while a good suggestion I dont think the format of the config file is under his control ... but I could be totally wrong here ...

Comment: The config is not under my control. I aim to store all that information in MongoDB and be able to transform the configuration file into a JSON cause currently is using a different format which I wasn't able to identify.

Comment: The transformation should work both ways. From current configuration to JSON and the other way around as well.

Comment: so the configuration does sound like its under your control.  Just format the configuration like a python dictionary then you can load/dump it to/from JSON.